# Laravel Livewire emit or emit event not fire

Tags: laravel, events, controller, laravel-livewire

I am using **Laravel 10**, **Livewire 2.x** I am trying to use emit or `emitTo` event from a simple function in my `Livewire` components to update the wishlist count.

```
public function removeFromWishlist($id){
        $wishlist = Wishlist::findOrFail($id);
        $wishlist->delete();
        $this->emit('wishlistUpdated');
        session()->flash('message', 'Product Removed From Wishlist');
}
```

WishlistCount controller:

```
 protected $listeners = ['wishlistUpdated' => 'checkWishlistCount'];
    public $wishlistCount;

    public function checkWishlistCount(){
        if(Auth::check()){
            return $this->wishlistCount = Wishlist::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count();
        }else{
            $this->wishlistCount = 0;
        }
    }
```

It gives me an error when I run the function that method emit not exist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVbOM.png) Method emit Doesn't exist

also, when i run this code:

```
 $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('message', [
                'text' => 'Please Login To Continue',
                'type' => 'danger',
                'status' => 401
  ]);
```

It gives me the same error: Method `dispatchBrowserEvent` doesn't exist.

Whenever i use `$this->emit()`, `$this->emitTo()`, `$this->dispatchBrowserEvent()` or any method with `$this->`
it gives me an error that this method doesn't exist.

Comment: Sounds like Livewire isn't properly installed, what happens if you run `composer show -D`? What version of Livewire do you see there?

Answer (score 1):

you must use something like this

```
 $this->dispatch('message', [
            'text' => 'Please Login To Continue',
            'type' => 'danger',
            'status' => 401
```

]);

in livewire 3 emit , `dispatchBrowserEvent`  has changed to `dispatch`